# get content of h1 on index

Tags: jquery, indexing, alert

I will get the content of some h1 tag in some li tag.
I have made some simple fiddle but it doesn't work for me.

What I want is that the scripts alert "This is two".

JS:

```
$index = 1;

$item = $('ul').children('li').eq($index);
$itemname = $item("h1").text();
alert($itemname);
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>this is one</li>
    <li>hello
         <h1>this is two</h1>
    </li>
    <li>this is three</li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone help me?

[Here is the fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/5ppuweo4/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$item` is a jQuery object, not a function, you probably want to use `find()`

```
$itemname = $item.find("h1").text();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5ppuweo4/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the script a little. Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/5ppuweo4/5/

```
var itemname = $("h1").text();    
alert(itemname);
```

Hope it helps.